# I have to click a Jquery submit button twice

Tags: jquery

I have a simple div button which I have to click twice for the link to work.  How can this be stopped?

Thanks

```
<div class="toolbar">
  <table width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td class="toolbar-button" title="Print Data" id="btnNew1" onClick="javascript: submitformPrint();">
      <img src="'. IMAGES .'/Print.png" width="16" height="16" />
      <span>Print data</span>
    </td>
    <td width="100%" height="10" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

function submitformPrint(){
    $('#btnNew1').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $('#form2').attr({
            action: '../../../<?php echo CurrentVersion; ?>/Template/PopUpSimple.php?txtPageName=Pupils_TripsPrint',
            target: '_blank'
        });
        $('#form2').submit();
    });
}
```

Comment: On submit button you are executing a function which is actually binding click to btnNew1 again. I would recommend remove onsubmit handler from the form. Instead of submitformPrint use $(document).ready and add $('#btnNew1').click inside it

Comment: I don't relly understand the different element.  Are you able to show what you mean by altering my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code you have given is it has an onClick handler on the button.

```
<td class="toolbar-button" title="Print Data" id="btnNew1" onClick="javascript: submitformPrint();">
```

when you click btnNew1, you are then binding

```
$('#btnNew1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $('#form2').attr({
        action: '../../../<?php echo CurrentVersion; ?>/Template/PopUpSimple.php?txtPageName=Pupils_TripsPrint',
        target: '_blank'
    });
    $('#form2').submit();
});
```

It is the reason because of which you have to click button twice. Instead your code should look like below.

```
<div class="toolbar">
      <table width="100%">
       <tr>
        <td class="toolbar-button" title="Print Data" id="btnNew1">
          <img src="'. IMAGES .'/Print.png" width="16" height="16" />
          <span>Print data</span>
        </td>
        <td width="100%" height="10" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnNew1').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $('#form2').attr({
                action: '../../../<?php echo CurrentVersion; ?>/Template/PopUpSimple.php?txtPageName=Pupils_TripsPrint',
                target: '_blank'
            });
            $('#form2').submit();
        });
    }});
```

Comment: Fantastic.Worked a treat.

Comment: @Duncan I hope, you also understood why it was not working earlier :)